# Android Room: error: setValue(T) has protected access in LiveData

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm trying to get up and running with Android development and Room.

I'm making a music player app with playlists and a file browser that will be able to add tracks to the current playlist.

I'm saving the playlists in a Room database.

I'm running into the problem of running the program from the first time, and there not being any data in the database.

I want to query the database for the last playlist opened, but if there are no playlists in the database, I want to create an empty PlayList object.

```
 7    public class PlayListRepository
 8    {
 9        public PlayListRepository(Application application)
10        {
11           _application = application;
12        }
13
14        public LiveData<PlayListWithTracks> getPlayList(int playListId)
15        {
16            if (_appDao == null) {
17                InitDb();
18            }
19            LiveData<PlayListWithTracks> livePlayListWithTracks = _appDao.getByIdWithTracks(playListId);
20            if (livePlayListWithTracks.getValue() == null) {
21                livePlayListWithTracks.setValue(new PlayListWithTracks());
22            }
23            return livePlayListWithTracks;
24        }
25
26
27        private void InitDb()
28        {
29            AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(_application);
30            _appDao = db.appDao();
31        }
32
33        private Application _application;
34        private AppDao _appDao;
35    }
```

Line 21 doesn't compile.  It says `error: setValue(T) has protected access in LiveData`.

My `AppDao.getByIdWithTracks` method looks like this:

```
@Dao
public interface AppDao
{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PlayList WHERE Id = :id")
    LiveData<PlayListWithTracks> getByIdWithTracks(int id);
}
```

I've tried casting `livePlayListWithTracks` to `MutableLiveData<PlayListWithTracks>`, but that gives me a runtime error of `androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData`

I've tried casting it to `RoomTrackingLiveData`, but Android Studio doesn't recognize the `androidx.room` import.

Am I on the wrong track or what?

**Edit:** Here is PlayListWithTracks:

```
public class PlayListWithTracks
{
    @Embedded
    public PlayList playList;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "playListId"
    )
    public List<Track> tracks = new Vector<Track>();
}
```

Comment: show livePlayListWithTracks.setValue this method. Pls post the viewModel class code

Comment: The view model just calls the `getPlayList()` method that won't compile above.  I posted `PlayListWithTracks` if that helps.

Comment: In general, if you do not *create* the `LiveData`, you cannot *modify* the `LiveData`. In this case, you did not create the `LiveData` -- Room did. You are using Java, not Kotlin, which limits your options. Similarly, you are using `LiveData` from Room, rather than RxJava, which limits your options. Probably you can use `Transformations.map()` (e.g., in your viewmodel) to handle this "provide default results" scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought modifying data is what LiveData is for.  Actually, the only reason I put it into the DAO class is because Android won't let me run a query on the main UI thread.  Should I just get rid of the LiveData class once I get it from the database?  And then wrap the payload in a MutableLiveData because I need it to monitor changes made by the user?

Comment: @MattGregory: "I thought modifying data is what LiveData is for" -- yes, for the *creator* of the `LiveData`, not the *consumer*. In this case, you are only the consumer. "Should I just get rid of the LiveData class once I get it from the database?" -- typically no, as that would be how you find out about changes to the database. But, it depends on the scenario. "And then wrap the payload in a MutableLiveData because I need it to monitor changes made by the user?" -- typically, you would store the user changes in the database itself. But, again, it depends on the scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, it sounds like LiveData is a one-way data binding, and I was thinking of it as two-way.

Comment: @MattGregory: You can create subclasses of `LiveData`, or use `MutableLiveData`, or use `MediatorLiveData`, to be both the creator and (probably) the consumer of a `LiveData`. But if you get a `LiveData` from somebody else (such as Room or another library), you're just the consumer.

Answer (score 2):

`LiveData` represents the data in your database. If you modify that entry in the database from any other part of your application your `LiveData` will reflect that change. It serves no purpose to try and set another value to the `LiveData`.

If you do not require to observe changes in the Data then you can probably return the object in the Data Access Object. Like so:

```
@Dao
public interface AppDao
{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PlayList WHERE Id = :id")
    PlayListWithTracks getByIdWithTracks(int id);
}
```

Perhaps the better approach would be to create a new playlist entry in the database if it does not exist and then access that entry. Meaning that you could add a new `PlayListWithTracks` entity to the database with the `id` received in the function and then access that entity

Comment: Ok, this is starting to make sense.  I will try inserting a record in the database.  Thanks!